# How to do search/cluster over a million points?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, dbscan, tsne, semantic-similarity

I've a practical question in the areas of clustering/semantic search and would like to get some thoughts. Refer the figure for more details on this hypothetical situation.

Imagine I've 2 query embeddings (genre 1 and genre 2) and a bunch of movies I've embedded. Now, I need to limit my final list of movies that I recommend (assume the final list is limited to 20 recommendations. Also assume that each group in the figure has 10 movies for this situation).

So, I can do it in 2 ways:

1. *Global view* - Look at all the distances together and give the 20 closest movies to any of the genre (so the final list of movies will be group 1, 2)
2. *Local view* - Look at each query separately and give 10 closest movies (so the final list of movies will be group 1, 3)

Now, here's my thought process:

*Global view:* As I am giving the closest movies in global fashion, I reduce the False positives in my system. But I lose on the recall i.e I end up not having any movie recommended for genre 2.

*Local view:* As I am giving the closest movies in local fashion, I end up having a more representative recommendation system covering all genres. But I can end up in False positives (all movies in group 3 might not be relevant to genre 2; that's why high distance) and am missing out to recommend closer movies (group 2)

So, what's the best way to model the threshold in situations like this? Any high-level ideas, thoughts, references to academic publications, best practices are most welcome. I can share more details on the pipeline and methods I tried if it's helpful.

[image]

*Note:* The distances mentioned in the figure is for representation i.e it's not cluster distance or average distance and there're no groups! It's just for a clear explanation and to avoid cluttering. I've distances from query to every individual movie.

*Real-world situation:* I am dealing with ~30 million data points (each of 384-d) and have 10 queries. Assume for every query I've to return 100k closest items with least false-positives. So, any approach I follow has to be efficient (it's not time-sensitive)

**Current idea:** 30million embeddings --> FAISS (to limit to 1million closest points) --> t-SNE/UMAP (reduce 384-d to 50-d) --> HDBSCAN (to find the nearest cluster for a given query)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/recommendation